# What is the proper way to route ground from semiflush mount panel to grounding rod?

Tags: electrical

[[image]

I'm using #6 shielded grounding wire to go down inside wall then coming out to a rod in corner by bricks and continuing on outside attached to house around corner going 6 feet away to 2nd grounding rod. Is there a box or something I need to install where ground wire comes out of stucco or do I just fill around it with fire caulk or? thank you for all the help everyone. You all make me proud to be an electrician. Also how much do I leave the ground rod sticking up out of slab and do I need to put anykind of sleeve around the rod where it goes thru the concrete? I'm in southern California.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a j-box you can just fire caulk the hole. Be sure and strap down the ground wire. Ground rods should be driven completely into the ground, most AHJ let you leave a few inches above the soil to make the ground connection.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrcian   my two rods should go tucked in corner by fireplace bricks and then as close to the house along long wall 6 feet away? or do I need to be certain space away from house. Thank you

Comment: @cdguitarok - There is no space or clearance requirement that I am aware of, check out NEC Article 250.52 on grounding electrodes and see if there are any other  methods of grounding you can use also. AHJ in this area will tell you that they like you to use every method possible in commercial construction.